# Do "no cached" simulations give the same result in multiple computers?

Tags: rendering, particles, physics, cache

If a file has no disk cache and is rendered multiple times in multiple computers.. Does the physics simulation give the same result in every computer every time? *(same file and not changin' the seed)*

---

**EDIT**

Rendering with GPU and then CPU on different file locations gave same result.

Rendering on sheepit renderfarm splitting the frame into 8x8 tiles and so rendering on several different computers, gave corrected and same results.

[image: sheepit_rendering_test]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the properties of a physics item are the same, then yes. Physics will work the same way everytime, if there is no dynamic wind simulation in your scene or something. Its blender, not real life.

Comment: for dynamic wind You mean like keyframed at the first frame with a noise modifiers applied? thank You so far :)

Comment: Yes, something like that. An outside force that makes the simulation have a different outcome every time you start it.